# How to convert an array of JSON into an array of javascript object?

Tags: javascript, json

For example, this is the JSON array:

```
    [
     {
       "name":"Jennifer Bellingham",
       "shortname":"Jenni"
     },
     {
       "name":"Jonathan G. Ferrar II",
       "shortname":"Jonathan_Ferrar"
     }
    ]
```

And this is the format I want it to be converted (an array of javascript object) :

```
    [
     {
       name : "Jennifer Bellingham",
       shortname : "Jenni"
     },
     {
        name : "Jonathan G. Ferrar II",
        shortname : "Jonathan_Ferrar"
     }
    ]
```

I used `JSON.parse()` but I get this error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

This is my code:

**I have an angularjs app:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute','appControllers',
'ui.carousel']);
```

**And this is my controller: (I'm trying to use angularjs ui carousel)**

```
app.controller('uiCarousel', function($scope,$http) {
   $http.get('data/test.json').then(function(response){
        $scope.mySlides  = response.data;
        console.log("My Slides :", $scope.mySlides ); //I'm getting the result here
    });

    //But here I can't do the parsing right, 
    this.slides = JSON.parse($scope.mySlides);

});
```

**this.slides in the code above expects this formatting :**

```
       [
         {
           name : "Jennifer Bellingham",
           shortname : "Jenni"
         },
         {
            name : "Jonathan G. Ferrar II",
            shortname : "Jonathan_Ferrar"
         }
        ]
```

Comment: Neither of those are JSON, both are already Arrays of Objects

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Your question makes little sense, please create a snippet with the exact piece of code that yields an error. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The error is because JSON.parse parses a JSON string not an object/array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umm... JSON and javascript objects are kinda the same (latter can contain more things like functions, getters, setters, etc...)

I guess you are getting confused by the object literal writting style. `{"key": "value"}` and `{key: "value"}` is same.

So... `response.data` is actually a javascript object (which is equivalent to the JSON data)

Basically there's no need to parse anything...

```js
let a = [
 {
   "name": "Jennifer Bellingham",
   "shortname": "Jenni"
 },
 {
    "name": "Jonathan G. Ferrar II",
    "shortname": "Jonathan_Ferrar"
 }
];

let b = [
 {
   name: "Jennifer Bellingham",
   shortname: "Jenni"
 },
 {
    name : "Jonathan G. Ferrar II",
    shortname : "Jonathan_Ferrar"
 }
];

console.log(angular.equals(a,b));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

And that's the reason why you getting an error because you are trying to parse an already parsed JSON string.

For example look at this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/summary/JavaScript the response body of the api is JSON so fetching this is like fetching a .json file

Then `response.data` will be a javascript object... hence I can directly access `response.data.extract`

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
    $http
      .get("https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/summary/JavaScript")
      .then(function(response) {
        $scope.extract = response.data.extract;
      })
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">{{extract || "loading"}}</div>
```

Comment: Thank you my friend. You were also right, I could directly access the response without converting.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for submitting your first question.

It is a little unclear as to what code snippet actually gives the error you reference - if you could include that snippet, it might help us to understand your problem.

It might be that you're inputting an object into `JSON.parse` instead of a string.

The below code works for me - I've used backticks ` to create a string literal, contains the json string I wish to parse.

```js
const jsonString = `
    [
     {
       "name":"Jennifer Bellingham",
       "shortname":"Jenni"
     },
     {
       "name":"Jonathan G. Ferrar II",
       "shortname":"Jonathan_Ferrar"
     }
    ]
`;

const arrayOfObjects = JSON.parse(jsonString);

console.log(arrayOfObjects); // Returns the array of objects you reference
```

Comment: I'm getting the JSON data from a file called 'test.json' as I explained. I can't put that backticks to the file! how should I manage the parsing...